# Select Query giving different results

Tags: sql-server, select

I have written the select  fallowing query but it is giving different results surprisingly any wrong in the query. pls let me know. Query:

```
Select count(*) Count from conflux.dbo.SABR_Master M 
        Where M.Email in (
        select top 26 Email from conflux.dbo.SABR_Master L 
        where (L.titleid In (Select titleid From sabr_titlemasters Where IsDisplay=1 And  title like '%Account Executive%' OR title like '%Account Manager%' OR title like '%Accounts Manager%' OR title like '%admin%'  ))
        ) and M.Email NOT IN (select Email from [sample client].dbo.Comm_CompanyData)
```

Comment: pls format it your query

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
Select  count(*) Count 
from    conflux.dbo.SABR_Master M 
Where   M.Email in (select  top 26 
                            L.Email 
                    from conflux.dbo.SABR_Master L 
                    where (L.titleid In (   Select  titleid 
                                            From    sabr_titlemasters 
                                            Where   IsDisplay=1 And  
                                                    (title like '%Account Executive%' OR 
                                                    title like '%Account Manager%' OR 
                                                    title like '%Accounts Manager%' OR 
                                                    title like '%admin%')))
                    ORDER BY L.Email) and 
        M.Email NOT IN (select  Email 
                        from [sample client].dbo.Comm_CompanyData)
```

I have added brackets around your **title like** OR's and an Order By to keep your 26 emails the same. The database can return them in a random order if order by is not specified, which can give you different results.

Comment: Your `M.Email NOT IN` is being applied to the entire query, not the subquery.

Comment: sorry i dont know that thing. Thank you for your feed back. I will correct it. i dont repeat this mistake. Thank you